# Is it one-to-one relationship between std::future and std::promise?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the std::promise and the std::future.
For me, it seems that they are one-to-one relationships.
Am I understanding it right?

Is there any circumstance that can break this relationship?
I guess a broken promise means that the relationship is broken?
Thanks for sharing your ideas in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "one-to-one relationship"? An `std::promise` provides an `std::future` but there are also other standard library operations (such as `std::async`) that do the same

Comment: A default constructed `std::future` does not relate to a `std::promise` and at the time of creation of a `std::promise` there is no corresponding `std::future`; the future needs to be created via `std::promise::get_future`... Furthermore the future can get abandoned: `std::future<void> f; { std::promise<void> p; f = p.get_future(); }`

Comment: For one-to-one relationship, I mean if in one class I use promise (class P), in the other class (class F) I have future. Is it possible to have multiple objects of the class F,  if all the objects try to retrieve from promise, is it wrong approach? Thanks.

Comment: Future is not copyable, only movable. This means that assuming the types of the member variables are `std::future<T>` and `std::promise<T>` for some type `T`, only a single `F` can correspond to a `P` any given time, but there need not be such a object `F`...

Comment: Yes, it is only movable. Once it is moved, what will the next try to get the value from promise return?

Comment: @fabian Future has a `.share()` method to create a `shared_future` out of it, essentially making a promise correspond to an arbitrary amount of futures ...

Comment: @LorahAttkins No, the [description of `std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/share) states: *"Transfers the shared state of *this, if any, to a std::shared_future object. [...] After calling share on a std::future, valid() == false."*, i.e. when the function returns, there's no longer a `std::future` object corresponding to the `std::promise`

Comment: @fabian Sharing doesn't happen over a copy because we have different semantics for `valid()` and `get()`; future and shared future behave differently. The **state contained in a future** (if any) can only correspond 1-1 to a promise. But sharing is possible with a shared future, which is a different type obviously and needs to move-obtain ownership of the state from the source future. My comment pointed out that you can break 1-1 if you turn a future to a shared future. Your description of the shared future types contradicts a statement I never made; of course they are different types...

Comment: There are other ways to get a future reference other than std:: promise eg std:: packaged_task or std::async